# consulta no banco retornando array vazio

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Olá,
Tenho uma função para fazer consultas no banco.
Se a consulta retornar 1 ou mais linhas, a função retorna um objeto (ou uma classe), porém se a consulta não retornar nenhuma linha, o retorno é:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)
```

A função que faz a consulta:

```
    public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
        $query=$this->connect()->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute($params);

        if(isset($class)){
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS,$class) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }else{
            $rs = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) or die(print_r($query->errorInfo(), true));
        }

        return $rs;
    }
```

Gostaria de alguma sugestão para fazer essa função retornar apenas 0 se a  consulta não tiver linhas.
Obrigado desde  já.

Comment: E sua conexão? como que ta?

Comment: `private function connect(){
        try
        {
            $this->conexao = new PDO($this->getDBType().":host=".$this->getHost().";port=".$this->getPort().";dbname=".$this->getDB(), $this->getUser(), $this->getPassword());
        }
        catch (PDOException $i)
        {
            //se houver exceção, exibe
            die("Erro: <code>" . $i->getMessage() . "</code>");
        }
         
        return ($this->conexao);
    }`

Answer (score 0):

Depois de uma pausa para respirar e pensar um pouco, resolvi o  problema modificando a função select desta forma:

```
public function selectDB($sql,$params=null,$class=null){
        $q = $this->connect();
        $stmt = $q->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $res = array();
        if (isset($class)) {
            foreach($stmt as $row) {
                $res[] = $this->arrayToObject($row, $class);
            }
        } else {
            foreach($stmt as $row) {
                $res[] = $row;
            }
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Função arrayToObject:

```
private function arrayToObject(array $array, string $class_name){
        $r = new ReflectionClass($class_name);
        $object = $r->newInstanceWithoutConstructor();
        $list = $r->getProperties();
        foreach($list as $prop){
          $prop->setAccessible(true);
          if(isset($array[$prop->name]))
            $prop->setValue($object, $array[$prop->name]);
        } 
        return $object;
    }
```

Comment: Sugestão, use Early Returns, nunca use else pq aumenta a complexidade ciclomatica...